# ctrlp does not search any more in wild mode

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I updated ctrlp today, and it does not search any more.

For example, I have a list like this after I press `ctrl+p`

```
> a/b/c/d.js
> a/b/c/e.js
> a/b/c/f.js
```

then i entered `af`, it gave me nothing, it should give me `a/b/c/f.js` in previous version.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Yes, you missed the part where StackOverflow is not CtrlP's issue tracker.

Comment: since we have `ctrlp` tag here, why cannot I ask here?

Comment: Well, you can also ask on Quora or Yahoo Answers or any other general forum. Or you can directly use the plugin's issue tracker and get help from the plugin's maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has reverted to original match behavior

https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/commit/0404e56e674830de7a487af589a28c68b39cac90

Thanks to author